# Steam Error-118

Tags: steam

Last night I was trying to sell cards and level up when steam crashed. I could not get to the store or anything, and when it crashes it says,"Error Code: -118

Unable to connect to server. Server may be offline or you may not be connected to the internet." Now it lets me go to the store but when I try to go to my profile it just refreshes the store. How do you fix it?

Comment: It might be a temporary error. It is known that Steam was DDOSed yesterday. It might just resolve over time.

Comment: I had similar issues. Steam Community and many related steam destinations are down as of Jan 3, 2014. I am able to get good response using a general browser when viewing their "featured items", but the Steam client has a tremendously hard time doing anything at all currently. Don't panic--- it is Steam, not your local machine nor its configuration.